# need help understand how this PHP login array code works?

Tags: php, html, arrays

So the code at the bottom is an example code from my class of how to do a login page, it takes what is posted in an input box from an html file and receives this in a php file, the code then checks the username and password from an array and verify it or declines it, I can't understand what the syntax means in the if(), specifically the "isset($_POST['user']) && !isset($_SESSION['user'])" and such, I was hoping someone could break down what exactly each line does or what the syntax means? thanks for your time.

```
// (A) START SESSION
session_start();

// (B) HANDLE LOGIN
if (isset($_POST['user']) && !isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
  // (B1) USERS & PASSWORDS - SET YOUR OWN !
  $users = [
    "joe" => "123456",
    "jon" => "654321",
    "joy" => "987654"
  ];

  // (B2) CHECK & VERIFY
  if (isset($users[$_POST['user']])) {
    if ($users[$_POST['user']] == $_POST['password']) {
      $_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['user'];
    }
  }

  // (B3) FAILED LOGIN FLAG
  if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])) { $failed = true; }
}
```

Comment: This is too general. Please identify the spcecific parts that are confusing you. We're not going to explain basic PHP syntax like `if`.

Comment: This is basic stuff. Perhaps you need to read the PHP documentation? See: [Language Reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/langref.php). One thing you need to get comfortable with is putting in the work to understand something.

Comment: `if (isset($_POST['user']) && !isset($_SESSION['user']))` means "if an user name is submitted and no user is logged in".

Comment: This kind of thing is exactly what the teacher in your class is for, it's not really appropriate for this forum.  You should approach the teacher/tutor or your classmates

Comment: alright thanks for the tips and tricks, I'll keep it in mind

Answer (score 1):

isset = Check whether a variable is empty. here you are checking $_POST['user'] has any value set or not.

$_POST['user'] = there is a value sent to this page using post method, and name is 'user'

$_SESSION['user'] = there is a session named user
now

isset($_POST['user']) && !isset($_SESSION['user']))
means
check whether page received any post method named user and there isn't any session named user